# Memory allocation while declaring a variable to hold list of strings

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

```
std::vector<std::string> myList = new std::vector<std::string>();
```

would I be wrong in allocating memory like above? I do know the memory is allocated dynamically but was just wondering if it's possible to allocate memory using new operator.

Comment: the compiler will tell you that this won't work

Comment: yeah, I was just wondering if I was missing something.  Thanks @Matthias247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because `new std::vector<std::string>()` returns a pointer and on the left hand side you don't have a pointer.

There's nothing wrong with

```
std::vector<std::string> myList;
```

`new` is not needed.